# Split Multiple Words into Single Words (different rows) while Keeping all Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a searchterm report and would like to split that report into single words.

The original data looks like this:

[image]

This is the how I would want the data to look like:

[image]

I was trying it manually with splitting the words into columns and then paste them below each other, but that (with a large database) does not work.

Any ideas how I can split seachterms into multiple rows while keeping all the click-related data in place.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: VBA has a function called `Split` which works as advertised.  It will return an array that you can dump into the sheet in column A.  If you count those results, you can also copy/paste the starting row that many times and then output values in column A.  Take a stab at writing some code and then post back with your problems.

Answer (score 1):

- Copy the strings with all the words in it into a new sheet (to avoid
  overwriting).
- Click the cell/column with the strings
- Go to the 'Data' tab
- Use the 'Text to Columns' tool: Chose 'Delimited' on the first screen,
  hit next.
- Check the 'Space' box only and hit finish.
- *Your data could be split into Columns as before*
- Select the entire range and copy it
- Right-Click somewhere else and under the 'Paste' part of the menu
- click 'Transpose'.
- This will change all columns into rows and works on an infinite
  number of columns/Rows in theory. I've done it with 100 rows of 1000
  columns when an API only gives crapily formatted plain-text.